# Ansible : Recursively change ownership Except for a specific folder

Tags: ansible, devops

im new to ansible , i have this task that on deployment , it changes the ownership of the application files Recursively.

```
- name: Recursively change ownership
file:
  path: "{{ $PATH }}"
  state: directory
  recurse: yes
  owner: "{{ $USER }}"
  group: "{{ $USER }}"
notify:
  - Restart $service
when: deploy == "true"
```

I have a specific app folder binded to aws EFS , that's shared between different apps and i don't want to change the ownership for this folder.
I tried to add :

```
  fail : 
   when : ' "/$specific_folder " in {{ $PATH }} '
```

but it fails the whole task , also i can't remove the recurse because it fails the app to access other files. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did any answer helped?

Comment: hello @Khaled ,yes it did help , thank you .Both you and Houseem have the right answers , setting houssem's answer as solution since he delivered earlier . Thank you for your contrib .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for all files and directories in your parent folder with the 'find' module. Then, you pass the result as a list to a loop in a 'file' task. The 'file' task should test every item in the loop to check it does not belong to the excluded folder.

```
- name: "Find all files and folders in {{ PATH }}"
  find:
    path: "{{ PATH }}"
    file_type: any
    recurse: true
  register: folder_contents

- name: Recursively change ownership
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    owner: "{{ USER }}"
    group: "{{ USER }}"
  loop: "{{ folder_contents.files }}"
  notify:
    - Restart service
  when: 
    - deploy
    - item.path is not search(excluded_folder_name)
  vars:
    - excluded_folder_name: 'foobar'
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 1):

The file module doesn't recognise subdirectories:

```yaml
/tmp/testdir
├── folder1
├── folder2
└── specific_folder
```

```yaml
- name: Recursively change ownership
  file:
    path: /tmp/testdir/
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    owner: "{{ user }}"
    group: "{{ user }}"
```

```yaml
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "diff": {
        "after": {
            "path": "/tmp/testdir/"
        },
        "before": {
            "path": "/tmp/testdir/"
        }
    },
    "gid": 0,
    "group": "root",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "owner": "root",
            "path": "/tmp/testdir/",
            "recurse": true,
            "state": "directory",
        }
    },
    "mode": "0755",
    "owner": "root",
    "path": "/tmp/testdir/",
    "size": 4096,
    "state": "directory",
    "uid": 0
}
```

So we should find a way to get a list of subdirectories, which is [find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user: root
    path: /tmp/testdir/
  tasks:
  - name: list directories
    find:
      paths: "{{ path }}"
      file_type: any
    register: directories
```

Output(shrinked):

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
  "changed": false,
  "examined": 3,
  "files": [
      {
          "mode": "0755",
          "path": "/tmp/testdir/folder1",
          "pw_name": "root",
      },
      {
          "mode": "0755",
          "path": "/tmp/testdir/folder2",
          "pw_name": "root",
      },
      {
          "mode": "0755",
          "path": "/tmp/testdir/specific_folder",
          "pw_name": "root",
      }
  ],
  "invocation": {
  },
  "matched": 3,
  "msg": "All paths examined",
  "skipped_paths": {}
```

Now we got the output as an array calles `files` in the register `directories`.
 We can loop over the attribute `path` and set a condition to skip the task if the path includes name of the excluded directory.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user: root
    path: /tmp/testdir/
    exclude_dir: specific_folder
  tasks:
  - name: list directories
    find:
      paths: "{{ path }}"
      file_type: any
    register: directories
  
  - name: Recursively change ownership
    file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: directory
      owner: "{{ user }}"
      group: "{{ user }}"
    loop: "{{ directories.files }}"
    notify:
     - Restart service
    when: 
     - deploy
     - exclude_dir not in item.path
```

```yaml
TASK [Recursively change ownership] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/tmp/testdir/folder1', ....})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/tmp/testdir/folder2', ....})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'path': '/tmp/testdir/specific_folder', ...})
```

Comment: If you set the file_type to directories, you are skipping potential files that exist under"{{ path }}/. Those won't get their ownership changed. It's better to use 'any' instead.

Comment: Good point, but since it's recursive, only the skipped folder and its files would keep their permissions. I will test that.

Comment: @HoussemAZZOUZ as I said, only the skipped folder and its files would keep their permissions. It doesn't make sense to change files permissions under the skipped directory!

Comment: I'm referring to the 'main' or top-level folder that the user wants to change the permissions of its contents. 
If folder_A contains file1, sub_dir1 and sub_dir2. If you only look for directories within folder_A, you will miss file1. The permissions of file1 will not change.

Comment: Oh, I got your point. You're totally right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the tree

```
shell> pwd
/scratch/tmp8/test-992
```

```
shell> tree apps
apps
├── app1
│   └── app
├── app2
│   └── app
├── app3
│   └── app
├── file1
└── file2
```

```
shell> ls -la apps | grep app
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Sep  5 13:55 app1
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Sep  5 13:55 app2
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Sep  5 13:55 app3
```

```
shell> find apps -type f | xargs ls -la
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Sep  5 13:55 apps/app1/app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Sep  5 13:55 apps/app2/app
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Sep  5 13:55 apps/app3/app
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Sep  5 17:51 apps/file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 0 Sep  5 17:51 apps/file2
```

---

Declare the variables

```yaml
user: user2
path: apps
exclude: [app2, app3]

root: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
root_path: "{{ root }}/{{ path }}"
```

Find the files and directories

```yaml
    - name: Find any
      find:
        path: "{{ root_path }}"
        file_type: any
        recurse: true
      register: any
```

and declare the variables

```yaml
dirs_exclude: "{{ [root_path]|product(exclude)|map('join', '/')|list }}"
any_select: "{{ any.files|rejectattr('path', 'regex', dirs_exclude|join('|')) }}"
```

Change the ownership

```yaml
    - name: Change ownership of dirs and files
      file:
        state: "{{ item.isdir|ternary('directory', 'file') }}"
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: "{{ user }}"
        group: "{{ user }}"
      loop: "{{ any_select }}"
      when: item.isdir or item.isreg
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true

  vars:

    user: user2
    path: apps
    exclude: [app2, app3]

    root: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    root_path: "{{ root }}/{{ path }}"

    dirs_exclude: "{{ [root_path]|product(exclude)|map('join', '/')|list }}"
    any_select: "{{ any.files|rejectattr('path', 'regex', dirs_exclude|join('|')) }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Find any
      find:
        path: "{{ root_path }}"
        file_type: any
        recurse: true
      register: any

    - name: Change ownership of dirs and files
      file:
        state: "{{ item.isdir|ternary('directory', 'file') }}"
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        owner: "{{ user }}"
        group: "{{ user }}"
      loop: "{{ any_select }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
      when: item.isdir or item.isreg
```

Run the playbook in check and diff mode to see what will happen

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --check --diff

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Find any] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Change ownership of dirs and files] ****************************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-group: 1003
-owner: 1003
+group: 1004
+owner: 1004
 path: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/file2

changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/file2)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-group: 1003
-owner: 1003
+group: 1004
+owner: 1004
 path: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/file1

changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/file1)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-group: 1003
-owner: 1003
+group: 1004
+owner: 1004
 path: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/app1

changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/app1)
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-group: 1003
-owner: 1003
+group: 1004
+owner: 1004
 path: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/app1/app

changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp8/test-992/apps/app1/app)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```